# Why does Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory throw an IOException error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm fairly new into saving media in android, and I'm wondering why this is giving me so much trouble.  I am requiring photos taking by my app to be made public, so other apps (including the gallery) can find them.

The documentation states that it if you want an image to be accessible by other apps, you should save them on in the public external storage which is provided by `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, with the `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` as the argument.

When I try to do this however, the IOException is thrown in my method, and I'm struggling to find out why.

File creation method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Photo capture method:

```
public void capturePhoto (View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.auswide.auswidedashboard", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

Permissions and Provider code in the Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.auswide.auswidedashboard"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

And finally the path required by the provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.auswide.auswidedashboard/files/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

The exception message reads `I/System.out: java.io.IOException: Permission denied'`, which simply confuses me more as I though I gave it the permissions in the manifest?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That what does the exception's message say?  Add it to the question.

Comment: @StephenC thanks, added it now.

Comment: Permission denied to do what with what?

Comment: `File.createTempFile()` That file is not created. That is all.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` That is not very informative. `Toast.makeText(this, "IOException: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); return;` Add that return; as now you blindly continue as if nothing has happened.

Comment: `path="Android/data/com.auswide.auswidedashboard/files/Pictures"` That does not match getExternalStoragePublicDirectory.

Comment: `The documentation states that it if you want an image to be accessible by other apps, you should save them on in the public external storage which is provided by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), with the DIRECTORY_PICTURES as the argument.` That is outdated and certainly does not work for Android Q+;